# ¿Cómo actualizar documentos con Mongoose usando findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Soy nuevo en desarrollo web y estoy desarrollando un *backend* con [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/es/) y [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) para la gestión y publicación de libros y/o novelas web, con el fin de afianzar mis conocimientos.
Tengo este esquema que es un libro con sus respectivas propiedades:

```
"use strict";

import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //titulo del libro
  title: String,
  //descripcion del articulo
  description: String,
  //fecha de publicacion
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  //Imagen de portada
  image: String,
  //Tipo de libro
  type: String,
  //Generos del libro
  genders: String,
  //Estado del libro
  state: String,
  //capitulos del libro
  chapters: {
    //Numero del capitulo
    numcap: String,
    //Titulo del capitulo
    titlecap: String,
    //fecha de publicacion del capitulo
    datechapter: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    //Paginas
    imgpage: {
      //Numero de pagina
      numpage: { type: Array, default: [] },
      //Imagen de pagina (las paginas de cada capitulo se guardaran como un string de la url de cada imagen)
      imgpage: { type: Array, default: [] },
    },
  },
});

export default mongoose.model("Article", ArticleSchema);
```

ya puedo ingresar los datos principales del libro, ahora ¿como debería ingresar los datos de los capítulos y sus páginas? ya lo intente con el método `findOneAndUpdate()`, tengo este código en el controlador:

```
saveChapter: (req, res) => {
    //Recoger el id del articulo por la url
    var articleId = req.params.id;

    //Recoger lo datos que llegan por put
    var params = req.body;

    //Validar los datos
    try {
      var validator_numcap = !validator.isEmpty(params.numcap);
      var validator_titlecap = !validator.isEmpty(params.titlecap);
      var validator_numchapter = !validator.isEmpty(params.numpage);
      var validator_imgchapter = !validator.isEmpty(params.imgpage);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        status: "error",
        message: "Error faltan datos",
      });
    }

    if (
      validator_numcap &&
      validator_titlecap &&
      validator_numchapter &&
      validator_imgchapter
    ) {
      //Asignar valores

      var datos = new Object();

      datos.numcap = params.numcap;
      datos.titlecap = params.titlecap;
      datos.numpage = params.numpage;
      datos.imgpage = params.imgpage;

      articleModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: articleId },
        datos,
        { new: true },
        (err, articleUpdated) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(404).send({
              status: "error",
              message: "No se pudo guardar los datos",
            });
          }

          if (!articleUpdated) {
            return res.status(404).send({
              status: "error",
              message: "No hay datos para mostrar",
            });
          }

          return res.status(200).send({
            status: "success",
            article: articleUpdated,
          });
        }
      );
```

Agradezco a quien pueda ayudarme con responderme que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

**RESUMEN**

Para actualizar documentos necesitas saber de antemano el tipo de actualización. Tu Esquema indica que no tienes muy clara la forma en que vas a almacenar la información. Tienes un campo `chapters` pero sólo almacena un documento. Un libro tiene por norma general más de 1 capítulo. Luego tienes un documento embebido en el que pretendes almacenar un valor de número de página y un valor de la `url` de la imagen que hay en dicha página, pero lo haces en 2 `arrays` diferentes.

Has de cambiar esto:

```js
imgpage: {
  numpage: [],
  imgpage: []
}
```

por esto otro:

```js
imgpage: [
  { numpage: Number, image: String}
]
```

Esto hará que Mongoose cree un `Array` y podremos introducir documentos que contengan las propiedades adecuadas.

**Nota** Mongoose creará un campo `_id` para cada subdocumento de este `array`, si no deseamos eso, basta con definir un campo `_id` con valor `false`:

```js
imgpage: [
  { _id: false, numpage: Number, image: String}
]
```

Para añadir un documento nuevo al `array` hacemos uso del operador [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) de MongoDB. Por ejemplo:

```js
let update = { 
  $set: {
    chapter.numcap = params.numcap,
    chapter.titlecap = params.numcap,
  },
  $push: {
    chapter.imgpage: { numpage: params.numpage, image: params.imgpage }
  }
}
```

Si deseamos actualizar un elemento existente en el `Array` debemos usar un [identificador](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) y la opción [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters). Por ejemplo:

```js
let update = {
  $set: {
    chapter.numcap = params.numcap,
    chapter.titlecap = params.numcap,
    "chapter.imgpage.$[identifier_name].image": params.imgpage
  }
}

let options = {
  new: true,
  arrayFilters: [{ "identifier_name.numpage": params.numpage}]
}
```

En ambos casos, se usa el método pasando el objeto `update` y `options` como lo dice la documentación:

```
model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: articleId}, update, options, callback);
```

---

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea actualizar un documento de MongoDB mediante el método [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com).

El esquema del documento indica que tienes campos de con subdocumentos o lo que comúnmente se conoce como [datos embebidos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/#embedded-data).

Tu esquema:

```js
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  image: String,
  type: String,
  genders: String,
  state: String,
  // esto es un campo con datos embebidos
  chapters: {
    numcap: String,
    titlecap: String,
    datechapter: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    // esto es un campo con datos embebidos
    imgpage: {
      numpage: { type: Array, default: [] },
      imgpage: { type: Array, default: [] },
    },
  },
});
```

En tu esquema de datos tienes 3 niveles. El primer nivel contiene un campo llamado `chapters` el cual almacena un subdocumento. Los campos de este subdocumento son o están en el segundo nivel. Entre estos campos, hay uno llamado `imgpage`, que almacena un subdocumento, los campos de este subdocumento son o están en el tercer nivel.

Si yo deseo obtener el `Array` de `numpage` almacenado en `imgpage` debo hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
const imgNumpages = doc.chapters.imgpage.numpage; // es un array
```

Siendo `doc` un documento de la colección `articles` en MongoDB.

Si esta es la forma en la que obtengo un valor, lo mismo aplica para actualizar un valor.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Existen diversas formas de realizar la actualización de datos dado tu esquema. Intentaré explicar de forma clara cómo hacerlo sin perder de vista la eficiencia.

Lo primero que debemos tomar en cuenta es el método que vamos a usar. Ya que dependiendo de esto, la actualización del documento puede ser sencilla o compleja.

Leyendo la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) del método `findOneAndUpdate()` vemos que el mismo recibe los siguientes parámetros:

- Condiciones: Objeto que indica las condiciones de búsqueda dentro de la colección. El método devolverá el primer documento que coincida con estas condiciones de búsqueda.
- Actualización: Objeto que representa la actualización sobre los campos del documento. *Nota: Todas las operaciones de actualización realizadas sobre las claves de nivel superior, que no sean [operaciones atómicas](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/#pattern) serán tratadas como operaciones de tipo `set`. Esto previene sobre escribir el documento con el valor del Objeto actualización*.
- Opciones: Objeto de opciones, entre las cuales podemos enviar `{ new: true }` para indicar que deseamos obtener el documento actualizado y no el documento antes de la actualización.
- Callback: Función opcional, si es pasada como argumento, se ejecutará la consulta y el resultado será enviado como argumento a nuestra función. Si no es pasada, el método devolverá un Objeto tipo [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query).

Aclarado esto, vamos a centrarnos en el Objeto de Actualización, para saber cómo actualizar los campos embebidos de nuestro documento.

Pero antes de continuar, vamos a corregir ciertos detalles de la semántica del código empleado.

En tu código puedo apreciar que usas sintaxis [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), por lo tanto, escribir `"use strict";` al principio de tu código no tiene ningún efecto, ya que semanticamente, los módulos de ES6 compilan en [modo estricto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Modo_estricto).

Por otro lado, es algo chocante ver el uso de sintaxis ES6 junto con la antigua sentencia `var` para la declaración de variables. No digo que no puedas usarla, solo digo que no deberías usarla. Siempre es preferible `let` y `const`.

**Objeto Actualización**

Basándome en el código aportado en tu pregunta, veo que tienes los siguientes valores para actualizar tu documento:

1. `numcap`: Propiedad del objeto embebido en la clave de primer nivel `chapter`.
2. `titlecap`: Propiedad del objeto embebido en la clave de primer nivel `chapter`.
3. `numpage`: Propiedad del objeto embebido en la clave de segundo nivel `imgpage`.
4. `imgpage`: Propiedad del objeto embebido en la clave de segundo nivel `imgpage`.

Tenemos entonces que escribir la estructura apropiada de actualización:

```js
let update = { $set:
  {
    chapter.numcap = params.numcap,
    chapter.titlecap = params.numcap,
    chapter.imgpage.numpage = params.numpage,
    chapter.imgpage.imgpage = params.imgpage // ???
  }
}
```

Como los campos a actualizar no son de nivel superior, debo usar el operador [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) de MongoDB.

Este primer intento me hace plantearme 3 preguntas:

1. ¿Porqué un campo embebido tiene el mismo nombre que su antecesor? Eso es poco intuitivo a la hora de que otros desarrolladores lean tu código. Además de traer confusión sobre el campo que deseo actualizar, es decir, ¿voy a actualizar el campo `imgpage` de segundo nivel o el de tercer nivel?.
2. Si actualizo el campo `numpage` e `imgpage` (de tercer nivel), los cuales son de tipo `Array`, ¿voy a sustituir dicho `Array` o voy a añadir un elemento al mismo? Si lo voy a sustituir, entonces, es necesario un `Array`?
3. ¿Qué relación guardan entre sí los campos de tercer nivel? Es decir, en los comentarios de tu código dice lo siguiente:

```js
//Páginas
imgpage: {
  //Número de página
  numpage: { type: Array, default: [] },
  //Imagen de pagina (las páginas de cada capítulo se guardarán como un string de la url de cada imagen)
  imgpage: { type: Array, default: [] },
},
```

Al parecer, el propósito de `imgpage` de segundo nivel es guardar o almacenar un índice o mapa o diccionario que relacione 1 página que contiene una imagen con la `url` a la imagen almacenada en algún lugar.

Así, puedo pensar que si pido todos los valores de `imgpage` me retorne algo que pueda relacionar `numpage` con su imagen. Y tal como lo tienes esa relación no parece mantener coherencia, porque nada me garantiza que el índice del elemento del `array` en `numpage` se corresponda con el índice del elemento en el `array` de `imgpage`.

Si este fuera el caso (no lo aclaras en la pregunta), mi sugerencia es que cambies tu modelo de datos de la forma siguiente:

```js
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //Título del libro
  title: String,
  //Descripción del artículo
  description: String,
  //fecha de publicación
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  //Imagen de portada
  image: String,
  //Tipo de libro
  type: String,
  //Generos del libro
  genders: {type: Array, default[]} // puedes tener 1 libro con más de 1 género
  //Estado del libro
  state: String,
  //capítulos del libro
  chapters: { // ¿Un libro puede tener más de un capítulo?
    //Número del capítulo
    numcap: String,
    //Título del capítulo
    titlecap: String,
    //fecha de publicación del capítulo
    datechapter: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    //Páginas <- aquí propongo el cambio
    imgpage: [
      {
        //Número de página
        numpage: Number,
        //Imagen de página
        image: String
      }
    ]
  },
});
```

Como no conozco a ciencia cierta el uso de tu colección te dejo en el aire esta pregunta. ¿Vas a almacenar 1 sólo capítulo a la vez en tu documento? Porque de momento es lo que hace tu esquema.

Volviendo al cambio propuesto para el campo `imgpage` embebido en `chapters`, vemos que lo he declarado de tipo `Array` y lo que se almacena dentro tiene una estructura de tipo asociativa (un documento u objeto) con 2 propiedades: `numpage` e `image`. Así cada elemento del `Array` en `imgpage` es un objeto que asocia claramente una página con la `url` de la imagen.

Nuestro objeto de actualización entonces cambiará, pero antes de mostrarlo, vamos a plantear 2 situaciones comunes al momento de actualizar un documento.

- Actualizar mediante la inclusión de nuevos valores en el `Array` de `imgpage`.
- Actualizar un elemento existente en el `Array`.

En el primer caso, simplemente debemos añadir un elemento a nuestro `Array`. Para esto vamos a usar el operador [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push).

Nuestro objeto de actualización quedaría así:

```js
let update = { 
  $set: {
    chapter.numcap = params.numcap,
    chapter.titlecap = params.numcap,
  },
  $push: {
    chapter.imgpage: { numpage: params.numpage, image: params.imgpage }
  }
}
```

En este objeto de actualización estoy pasando dos operadores de actualización: `$set` y `push`, ya que por un lado actualizaré campos de tipo `String` y por otro lado añadiré elementos a un campo de tipo `Array`.

Ahora, si lo que necesito es actualizar un elemento ya existente en el `Array`, debo realizar otro tipo de actualización.

Para ello vamos a introducir el operador [`$[identifier]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) de MongoDB y la propiedad [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) del objeto de opciones que podemos pasar como argumento al método `findOneAndUpdate`.

La idea de usar un identificador para el elemento que vamos a actualizar es ubicar con exactitud el elemento dentro del `array`, sin importar su posición.

Supongamos que nuestro `Array` contiene muchos elementos:

```js
imgpage: [
  {numpage: 2, image: 'url_value...'},
  {numpage: 5, image: 'url_value...'},
  {numpage: 7, image: 'url_value...'},
  //...
  {numpage: 145, image: 'url_value...'}
]
```

Si deseamos actualizar el valor del campo `image` correspondiente a la página definida por `params.numpage`, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
let update = {
  $set: {
    chapter.numcap = params.numcap,
    chapter.titlecap = params.numcap,
    "chapter.imgpage.$[identifier_name].image": params.imgpage
  }
}

let options = {
  new: true,
  arrayFilters: [{ "identifier_name.numpage": params.numpage}]
}
```

Como podemos observar, el nombre del identificador lo escogemos nosotros, lo importante es usar el mismo nombre para referirnos al elemento del `Array` que estamos actualizando.

Si analizamos el código en `arrayFilters`, podemos observar que el filtro nos indica que actualizaremos un elemento del `Array` que tenga como valor para su propiedad `numpage` el mismo valor que tenemos en `params.numpage`.

Te preguntarás el porqué indico los campos usando "comillas". A diferencia de los otros campos, MongoDB analiza el `string` pasado como nombre de campo y no el nombre de la variable en caso que no pasemos las comillas.

Aunque Mongoose es quien maneja la llamada al Driver de NodeJS para MongoDB, somos nosotros los encargados de escribir el código de forma correcta para que el manejador de Base de datos pueda realizar correctamente la operación. Y la documentación de MongoDB, establece que los nombres de los campos en operaciones CRUD deben ir entre comillas, para diferenciarlos de los operadores de consulta, como los que hemos usado: `$set` y `$push`, por ejemplo.

Por último, el código completo para tu método `findOneAndUpdate()` podría verse de la siguiente forma:

**Añadir un nuevo elemento al campo `imgpage`:**

```js
let update = { 
  $set: {
    chapter.numcap = params.numcap,
    chapter.titlecap = params.numcap,
  },
  $push: {
    chapter.imgpage: { numpage: params.numpage, image: params.imgpage }
  }
};

let options = { new: true };

model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: articleId}, update, options, callback);
```

**Actualizar un elemento del campo `imgpage`:**

```js
let update = {
  $set: {
    chapter.numcap = params.numcap,
    chapter.titlecap = params.numcap,
    "chapter.imgpage.$[elem].image": params.imgpage
  }
}

let options = {
  new: true,
  arrayFilters: [{ "elem.numpage": params.numpage}]
}

model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: articleId}, update, options, callback);
```

Espero que esto aclare las dudas que tenías sobre como realizar o llevar a cabo la actualización de documentos en MongoDB usando el método `findOneAndUpdate` de Mongoose.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, esta muy bien explicado y me quedo claro, muchas gracias!!